# Is vscode-python pipenv auto-run behavior a security risk?

Tags: python, security, visual-studio-code

I have a project (created by a friend) that contains a `Pipfile`. I just opened the folder in VSCode and upon opening a file, got this message:

`Workspace contains pipfile but attempt to run 'pipenv --venv' failed with 'spawn pipenv ENOENT'. Make sure pipenv is on the PATH.`

Ignoring the fact that the project setup is borked, I am surprised and concerned that the VSCode python extension is automatically running pipenv.

My Question is: should I not open untrusted folders in VSCode? My reasoning is that if I opened a malicious folder (e.g. pretending to be an open source library), then VSCode appears to auto-run pip installation, and from what I know of pip, it seems likely that you could place a malicious executable in the PATH (even if it's just in the VSCode workspace environment) that the user then invokes accidentally. So it seems like just by attempting to **look at** an untrusted folder I could get pwned. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then VSCode appears to auto-run pip installation

The Python Extension in VS Code is not auto installing pip. Note, this is `pipenv` and not `pip`.
The command `pipenv --venv` merely checks whether there's a virtual environment associated with the current directory and prints that information. See here https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pipenv

> So it seems like just by attempting to look at an untrusted folder I could get pwned

Once again, it does not install anything. That's not what the command `pipenv --venv` does.